# How do I give the <ul> a different color background from the rest of the page in html

Tags: html, css, colors, background, html-lists

(This is a project for a class I'm taking.)
This is what I have so far, but I can not figure out how to change the `<ul>` background color. We are not using the separate CSS so this will all be in my HTML document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    text-align: left;
}

h3 {
    text-align: left;
}

body {
    background-color: pink;
}

* {
 font-size: 120%;
 font-family: Arial Narrow;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Yada yada!</h1>

<h2>Yada yada:</h2>
<p>Our mission is to yada yada yada yada.</p>

<h3>Why you should get a membership at Yada Yada:</h3>
<ul>
<li>Better yada</li>
<li>Better yada</li>
<li>YADA YADA</li>
</ul>
<p>Yada yada is never out of style!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use a CSS class or ID.

Comment: If the `body { background-color: pink }` rule changes the background color of the `<body>` element, what do you think the rule should be to change the color of a `<ul>` element?

Answer (score 0):

You're in the right direction. Simply make a new declaration for `ul` like you did with `body` and specify a different `background-color` than `pink`.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a `background-color` directly to a `ul`, or virtually any element for that matter.

```
ul {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

That will change background just for UL elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    text-align: left;
}

h3 {
    text-align: left;
}

body {
    background-color: pink;
}

* {
 font-size: 120%;
 font-family: Arial Narrow;
}
ul{
    background-color: blue;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Yada yada!</h1>

<h2>Yada yada:</h2>
<p>Our mission is to yada yada yada yada.</p>

<h3>Why you should get a membership at Yada Yada:</h3>
<ul>
<li>Better yada</li>
<li>Better yada</li>
<li>YADA YADA</li>
</ul>
<p>Yada yada is never out of style!</p>

</body>
</html>
```